# Write a program that reads an input file and two strings representing the lower and upper bounds. Determine if the strings are in range and output

Tags: list, file, input, range

Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file, followed by two strings representing the lower and upper bounds of a search range. The file should be read using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains a list of alphabetical, ten-letter strings, each on a separate line. Your program should determine if the strings from the list are within that range (inclusive of the bounds) and output the results.

Ex: If the input is:

input1.txt
ammoniated
millennium
and the contents of input1.txt are:

aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
philosophy
quadratics
transcript
wilderness
zoologists
the output is:

aspiration - in range
classified - in range
federation - in range
graduation - in range
millennium - in range
philosophy - not in range
quadratics - not in range
transcript - not in range
wilderness - not in range
zoologists - not in range
Notes:

End the output with a newline.
All input files are hosted in the zyLab and file names can be directly referred to. input1.txt is available to download so that the contents of the file can be seen.
In the tests, the first word input always comes alphabetically before the second word input.

This is the code that I have so far, but it does not print out in alphabetical order.

## Type your code here.

```
file_name = input()
lower = input()
upper = input()

user_file = open(file_name)

word_list = user_file.readlines()
new_list = []
bad_list = []

for word in word_list:
    word = word.strip('\n')
    #
    if( word >= lower and word <= upper ):
        new_list.append(word)
    
    else:
        bad_list.append(word)
    
for new_word in new_list:
    print(new_word, "- in range")
    
for word in bad_list:
    print(word, "- not in range")`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the words in alphabetical order, why not take advantage of the fact that the input file is in alphabetical order? If I just use the logic of your code and simplify it to print out if a word is within bounds, while I am iterating through the list of words, then that takes care of the alphabetization requirement.

```
file_name = input()
lower = input()
upper = input()

user_file = open(file_name)

word_list = user_file.readlines()

for word in word_list:
    word = word.strip('\n')
    if word >= lower and word <= upper:
        print(word, "- in range")
    
    else:
        print(word, "- not in range")
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much for the help,.

Comment: Glad I could help Aiden. If you believe my answer adequately addresses your question, feel free to mark it as the "accepted answer." Hope you learned something!